# angularjs onclick need to fetch value corresponding to particular clicked value from another data set and display on div

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and my js file as follows:

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
  {
    $scope.ProdMenu = [
          {ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
          {ProductMenuName: "ABC"}
        ];
        
        $scope.categories = [
          {categoryName: "CBS1", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "CBS2", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "ABC1",ProductMenuName: "ABC"},
          {categoryName: "ABC2",ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "PQR1", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
          {categoryName: "PQR2", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
        ];
        
        
         $scope.setMaster = function(section) {
            console.log(section.ProductMenuName);
            
        }

});
```

First I am populating the productnames in a listview as follows:

```
    <body ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left " role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="ProdMenu in ProdMenu">
        <a href="" ng-click="setMaster(ProdMenu)">{{ProdMenu.ProductMenuName}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div id="category">
 <ul><li></li></ul>
</div
```

There you can see a function `ng-click="setMaster(ProdMenu)"`.

I have another `div category`. I want to display categories corresponding to that particular products to be displayed in div category.

In the following function:

```
$scope.setMaster = function(section) {
            console.log(section.ProductMenuName);
            
        }
```

.
I am getting the clicked productname.

**Suppose I am clicked CBS from list then I should get CBS1, CBS2 in category div**

How can I do this? please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat and filter. Here is a [working plunker based on your code and data.](https://plnkr.co/edit/4JiKcrzqIZAuf8xEMbVm?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left " role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="ProdMenu in ProdMenu">
      <a href="" ng-click="setMaster(ProdMenu)">{{ProdMenu.ProductMenuName}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="category" ng-repeat="category in categories | filter: {ProductMenuName:master} ">
    <ul>
      <li>{{category.categoryName}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.master = 'undefined';

  $scope.ProdMenu = [
      {ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
      {ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
      {ProductMenuName: "ABC"}
    ];

    $scope.categories = [
      {categoryName: "CBS1", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
      {categoryName: "CBS2", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
      {categoryName: "ABC1",ProductMenuName: "ABC"},
      {categoryName: "ABC2",ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
      {categoryName: "PQR1", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
      {categoryName: "PQR2", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
    ];


     $scope.setMaster = function(section) {
        console.log(section.ProductMenuName);
        $scope.master = section.ProductMenuName;

    }

});
```

Comment: Ty buddy it helped

Comment: Your welcome. Please note that when your start the app, I filter out / hide all the category by setting $scope.master to a dummy value 'undefined.' If you want to display all the categories at the start, you can replace $scope.master = 'undefined'; to $scope.master = undefined; (without the quote.) You could remove that trick and use ng-show='master' with $scope.master = undefined; This way the categories only show when master has a value.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qnuhHN7UP0mbAeCTbfkd?p=preview) I did a working Plunker of what you need. I used [Angular's filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for doing this.

It shows the list of `$scope.ProdMenu` and when you click a `ProdMenu`, it show the associated categories of `$scope.categories`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="p in ProdMenu">
            <a ng-click="setMaster(p)">{{p.ProductMenuName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="category">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="c in categories | filter: current.ProductMenuName: c.ProductMenuName">
                {{c.categoryName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
angular.module('mainModule', []).controller('mainController',['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.ProdMenu = [
          {ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
          {ProductMenuName: "ABC"}
        ];

        $scope.current = undefined;

        $scope.categories = [
          {categoryName: "CBS1", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "CBS2", ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "ABC1",ProductMenuName: "ABC"},
          {categoryName: "ABC2",ProductMenuName: "CBS"},
          {categoryName: "PQR1", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
          {categoryName: "PQR2", ProductMenuName: "PQR"},
        ];


        $scope.setMaster = function(section) {
          $scope.current = section;
        }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.currentCategories = [];

$scope.setMaster = function(section) {
    $scope.currentCategories = $scope.categories.filter(function(c) {
        return c.categoryName === section.ProductMenuName;
    });
};
```

And in your html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in currentCategories">{{category.categoryName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a $scope variable in your setMaster() func to filter the categories.

**Controller**

```
$scope.setMaster = function(section) {
  $scope.selected = section.ProductMenuName;
};
```

**HTML**

```
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories | filter: {ProductMenuName: selected}">
    {{ category.categoryName }}
  </li>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zNdts1qjqp85R535ehgj?p=preview) with the entire solution.